# How do I insert a string after every 50 words using php

Tags: php, html, css

I have to insert a `<br>` tag after every 52 words so that it displays a line break otherwise the paragraph keeps going on and on increasing its width rather that the height. If there is any other, better way, please tell me.

My code

```
<?php

$str = "Hello world. My name is Yash Mathur and I am a student. 
        I need help in this question as this is getting on my nerves, so I came to 
        stackoverflow.com 
        to seek for an answer. Please help me insert a line break after every 52 characters. 
        Thanks in advance!";
$len = strlen($str);
if ($len > 52) {
    $str = substr($str, 0, 52) . "<br>";
}
echo $str;
?>
```

I need to somehow put this in a loop to insert the `<br>` tag every 52 characters.

Comment: How are you printing this? It's a CSS issue if the browser doesn't break the lines automatically.

Comment: Even list items should break lines automatically. Can you make a jsfiddle or show the li's CSS?

Comment: Have you tried setting `white-space:normal` on your text-container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit div width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641195/how-to-limit-div-width)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607881/how-to-limit-width-of-a-div

Comment: Is it 52 or 50? Words or characters? Is the question really about how to line-break the text, or is it about how to make it look a certain way in the web page (and the line-breaks are just a guess about how to do that)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume what you are trying to achieve in the end, is just a decent-looking paragraph, whose line-length is not too long, as to become hard to read. I believe this is a cosmetic issue, that can be better addressed in the presentation layer of your application, i.e. the style sheet.

In the style belonging to the paragraph, you could just add a "width:250px" (250px is an arbitrary value) to constrain the text into a self-wrapping box that is defined by the width of the paragraph.

I would not do it in PHP unless there is a really valid reason for this, because, if you ever need to change the look of your paragraph, you would then have to delve into your PHP code. This might seem trivial now, but in a couple months you probably will not even remember writing such code in the first place. This will lead to a minor headache at best, and a great deal of wasted time searching for just this formatting function.

Please rethink your strategy.

Comment: setting the size in % makes it relative to the container of that element. Nothing wrong with that, but you have to have the container's width specified somehow, for this to work. If the container and the container's container (and so on) do not have a specified size (width in your case), the browser keeps looking upwards the tree until it eventually hits the document root element and uses that as the basis for the measurement.

On the other hand, using px gives an absolute size, which might be just what you are looking for if you are into fixed (non-elastic) layouts.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following code:

```
$original = "some long string";
$parts = str_split($original, 50);
$final = implode("<br>", $parts);
```

Comment: This would insert '<br>' every 50 chars not words

Comment: @Ivan, See the requirements: "I need to somehow put this in a loop to insert the <br> tag every 52 characters. "

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. But this doesn't check if you're splitting a line in the middle of a word and you'll end up with an ugly output. Try using CSS instead :)

```
<?php
$str = "Hello world. My name is Yash Mathur and I am a student. I need help in this question as this is getting on my nerves, so I came to 
stackoverflow.com to seek for an answer. Please help me insert a line break after every 52 characters. Thanks in advance!";
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($str); $i++) {
   if ($i % 52){
    echo mb_substr($str, 0 , 52) . '<br />';
    $str = mb_substr($str, 52, mb_strlen($str));
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$string='Lorem ipsum...';
$parts=explode(' ',$string);
$result='';
foreach ($parts as $key=>$part)
{
  $result.=$part.' ';
  if ($key%50==49)
    $result.='<br>';
}
```

However better way is to use [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
    $original = "Hello world. My name is Yash Mathur and I am a student. 
I need help in this question as this is getting on my nerves, so I came to 
stackoverflow.com 
to seek for an answer. Please help me insert a line break after every 52 characters. 
Thanks in advance!";

$parts = mb_split("\s", $original);
$final = "";
$newLineCount = 10;
$wordsCount = 0;
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if($wordsCount < $newLineCount){
        $final = $final . " ". $part;
        $wordsCount +=1;
    }else{
        $final = $final . "<br>". $part;
        $wordsCount = 0;
    }

}
echo $final ;
```

output:

[image: echo $final]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33697358)