# How to limit div width?

Tags: html, css, width

I have a div inside a table that is overflowing the screen size. It looks like this:

```html
<table id="hlavni" style=" position:absolute; border:none; position:relative; background-color:#FFC; border:#999 1px solid;" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td id="yamana" class="trida" valign="top" style="line-height:1.5em;">
            <div style="background-color:#FFC;" id=load_tweets>44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I prevent it from overflowing?

Comment: Are you looking for "max-width" css property?

Answer (score 10):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #limit {
        max-width: 500px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="limit">Your content goes here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok, when i do this my content starting to overflow... it didn't make that br what i was talking about...

Comment: It shouldn't do that, check out @Eray's jsfiddle. Works just fine there.

Comment: @esqew - Its work, but if there is no spaces, its not working...
Look on that: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YCV8H/6/)

Comment: @Sam007 If I would like the text to wrap, and not be hidden with ellipses, what is the way out?

Answer (score 5):

max-width and width -both- do not prevent the overflow **if the text does not contain any spaces** as in the example in the question.

```
div {
    max-width : 300px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmx0j65t/) for a solution.

For this case, the div must have the style "[word-wrap: break-word](http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/)"
in order to work.

Or "[overflow-wrap: break-word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)"

Answer (score 4):

With [max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) . Example : http://jsfiddle.net/YCV8H/