# How to limit width of a div?

Tags: css, html, width

I put a Google+ buttom on my site. This is the code:

```
<div id="gplus"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width="120"></div></div>

#gplus {
position: fixed;
bottom: 40px;
left: 5px;
z-index: 1;
width: 120px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

But the iframe that Google put into inner div is 1200px width and cover content. How to limit it? I fixed width of #gplus and add overflow:hidden but it doesn't help. :/

Comment: try this .g-plusone {width:120px;}

Comment: show me the link of this site

Comment: http://moitesmetki.com/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/evn/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new style definition to make the overflow inherit into the inner div. eg.

```
   #g-plusone {overflow:inherit;}
```

This won't work in IE7.

You may find that you need to add a class definition to the generated iframe so for instance add a class definition for

```
 #gplus iframe {width:120px;}
```

This will set any iframe in the #gplus div to have a width of 120px.

**UPDATE** : having looked at your site the following style should fix the issue

```
 #gplus iframe {min-width:120px !important;}
```

Google is setting the minimum width of it's frame, but you can override it by setting the min-width and using the important override.

Comment: #gplus div is transparent and I can see content below but I cant' touch anything below Google+ ifrmae button. When I add overflow:hidden  it seems to work but Chrome show me that iframe is 1200px width. :| This code doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

`max-width: 500px;` or any maximun width you want, in this way you can limit nor control the width of a element.