# How do I insert a character to string every nth width?

Tags: php

How do I insert a character to string every nth width?

e.g.

```
$input = 'テスaトテaストa’;

// Insert 'x' every 5th width
$output = 'テスaxトテaxストax’;
```

Comment: @harishsharma Word length is different from word width (e.g. `mb_strlen` vs `mb_strwidth`)

Comment: use mb_substr in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
<?php
$input = "テスaトテaストa";

$tempStr = '';
$count = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {

    $currChar = $input[$i];
    $countTemp = mb_strwidth($currChar);

    $count = $count + $countTemp;

    if($count == 7){
        $tempStr = $tempStr.$currChar.'x';
        $count = 0;
    }
    else{
        $tempStr = $tempStr.$currChar;
    }
}    

echo $tempStr; // will print テスaxトテaxストax
```

One more solution

```
<?php
function split($str, $len = 1) {
    $arr        = array();

    $length     = mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i += $len) {
        $arr[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $len, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $arr;
}

$input = "テスaトテaストa";

$parts = split($input, 3);
$final = implode("x", $parts).'x';

echo $final; // will print テスaxトテaxストax
```

Comment: The first one: nah, it's not dealing with multibyte characters properly. The second one: that's dealing with multibyte characters properly, but not with character widths…

Answer (score -2):

How @haris shama said, the solution it's available in [How do I insert a string after every 50 words using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7145026/5026957)

```
$parts = str_split($input, 5);
$final = implode("x", $parts);
```

Comment: I said width, not length (e.g. `mb_strlen` vs `mb_strwidth`)

Comment: `str_split` cannot deal with multibyte characters.